# Firebase Hosting - "Site not Found" when loading page with "www." prefix

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm currently working on deploying a site on firebase hosting, I want both domains:

charrocel.com & [www.charrocel.com](http://www.charrocel.com)

To load my website.

The problem I'm facing is that when I try to enter with `www.` prefix, I get the following error:

[image]

This is how custom domain looks on firebase hosting:

[image]

And this is how I have my DNS setup:

[image]

I've tried to point 'www' with an "A" record pointing the firebase IP but nothing. On firebase hosting, I've also tried to setup the [www.charrocel.com](http://www.charrocel.com) site as a separate domain but nothing.

Please, any help will be kindly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem may have been a configuration delay on the Firebase backend or a stale cache in your browser.
From my computer the https://www.charrocel.com URL correctly redirects to charrocel.com and the website looks OK.

Your problem is probably not caused by DNS because your [www.charrocel.com](http://www.charrocel.com) screenshot shows an error message generated by Firebase servers. DNS resolution worked.

If the problem persist on your side try checking the URL from an "incognito mode" / "private browsing" window.